How to change the css class in .aspx?
I am going to change the css class for each option is selected. The input block size should be adjusted though changing the css class. I checked the condition(value pass) and sure it is correct. It should be be something wrong on the overwriting the css class. I tried document.getelementbyid("<%= labSponser.ClientID %>").CssClass = "previewLabel1_1"; and Label lblEditor = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEditor") to change css class, seems that it is not work. How can I overwrite the old width here?
According the option have different size input box(background):

Now:

Target(Tune in F12 for test):

var selectoption = document.getElementById("<%= swapimgValue.ClientID %>");
var optionText = selectoption.options[selectoption.selectedIndex].text;

prompt("now reading", selectoption.selectedIndex); // check option

switch (selectoption.selectedIndex) {
  case "8":
    // document.getelementbyid("<%= labSponser.ClientID %>").CssClass = "previewLabel1_1";
    // document.getelementbyid("<%= labProgram.ClientID %>").CssClass = "previewLabel1_1";
    labSponser = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("labSponser");
    labSponser.CssClass = "previewLabel1_1";
    break;

  case "9":
    .......
}

// Css classes
span.previewLabel1 {
  width: 610px;
  verflow: hidden;
  display:block;
}
                    
/* -- Switch PTK length -- */
/* 1-9W */
span.previewLabel1_1 {
  width: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
}
/* 10-15W */ 
span.previewLabel1_2 {
  width: 385px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
}
/* 16-19W */     
/* 20-38W */  

// Input boxs
<tr><td valign="top" class="style3"> <asp:Label ID="labSponser" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#076ADB" CssClass="previewLabel1"></asp:Label></td></tr> 
<tr><td valign="top" height="8px"></td></tr> 
<tr><td valign="bottom" height="40px"> <asp:Label ID="labProgram" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="White" CssClass="previewLabel1"></asp:Label></td></tr>


"How can I overwrite the old width here" - if you do this that means CSS changes require a recompile and deploy. I'd recommend you edit the CSS file(s) and use different styles, this way the styles are split from the code logic. It's like MVC we separate the Controller from the View.

Yes, I already create other css class "span.previewLabel1_1 " to "span.previewLabel1_4" for different buttons. Then, I am sure that the CssClass in  need to switch with the "selectoption.selectedIndex" . Now stuck on how to changing the CssClass = "previewLabel1" to other created CssClass.. I tried some method search on internet and do not work. Now I don't know what to write inside the case8 switch.
